# Jupyter Bokeh: Non-existent column name in glyph renderer

Tags: python, jupyter, bokeh

I have a `GlyphRenderer` whose data_source.data is

```
{'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 'color': ['#3288bd', '#66c2a5', '#abdda4', '#e6f598', '#fee08b', '#fdae61', '#f46d43', '#d53e4f']}
```

The renderer's glyph is

```
Oval(height=0.1, width=0.2, fill_color="color")
```

When rendering, I see

```
E-1001 (BAD_COLUMN_NAME): Glyph refers to nonexistent column name: color [renderer: GlyphRenderer(id='1d1031f5-6ee3-4744-a0f7-22309798e313', ...)]
```

I'm clearly missing something, but this is pretty much lifted from published examples. I verified in a debugger that `data_source.column_names` is just `['index']`; what I don't understand is why the `'color'` column doesn't appear in the data source's `column_names`, or why Bokeh produces this warning (the graph appears to be correctly rendered).

The complete source is available at https://pastebin.com/HXAEEujP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's generally better to provide all relevant arguments when constructing an object rather than mutating the object after it's already been created. It's especially true for Bokeh - in many cases it does some additional work based on the arguments passed to `__init__`.

Take a look at this version of your code:

```
import math

from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import GraphRenderer, StaticLayoutProvider, Oval, GlyphRenderer, ColumnDataSource, MultiLine
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral8
from bokeh.plotting import figure

N = 8
node_indices = list(range(N))

plot = figure(title="Graph Layout Demonstration", x_range=(-1.1, 1.1), y_range=(-1.1, 1.1),
              plot_width=250, plot_height=250,
              tools="", toolbar_location=None)

node_ds = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(index=node_indices,
                                     color=Spectral8),
                           name="Node Renderer")
edge_ds = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(start=[0] * N,
                                     end=node_indices),
                           name="Edge Renderer")
### start of layout code
circ = [i * 2 * math.pi / 8 for i in node_indices]
x = [math.cos(i) for i in circ]
y = [math.sin(i) for i in circ]
graph_layout = dict(zip(node_indices, zip(x, y)))
graph = GraphRenderer(node_renderer=GlyphRenderer(glyph=Oval(height=0.1, width=0.2, fill_color="color"),
                                                  data_source=node_ds),
                      edge_renderer=GlyphRenderer(glyph=MultiLine(),
                                                  data_source=edge_ds),
                      layout_provider=StaticLayoutProvider(graph_layout=graph_layout))

plot.renderers.append(graph)

show(plot)
```

Comment: Thanks very much. No more warnings! Further, this looks like a much more sensible way to construct programs. I guess this is the price of early adoption in the Python world (or maybe should just just look for more up-to-date examples).